# ASP.NET MVC4 Mobile: CS0103: The name 'DisplayModes' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

Playing with a Mobile application in ASP.NET MVC4 beta, using great that [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features), but having issues with Display modes. Namely, I try to use

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ASP.NET Articles";
    DisplayModes.RequireConsistentDisplayMode = true;    
}
```

inside my _ViewStart.cshtml, but getting an complition error:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'DisplayModes' does not exist
>   in the current context

Does any one see that as well?

Comment: I would add that DisplayModes class is just not available for me at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked article is from September 12, 2011 so it seems they changed the API.

Try this (it works in MVC4 beta):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ASP.NET Articles";
    DisplayModeProvider.Instance.RequireConsistentDisplayMode = true;
}
```

Comment: You're probably better off setting `DisplayModeProvider.Instance.RequireConsistentDisplayMode = true` once in Application_Start in your Global.asax.cs, rather than setting it in your _ViewStart.cshtml which will run for every page request.